# fail to set setBackgroundResource, only sucess once the application run in android

Tags: android

```
public void ClearButtonColor(){
        for(int i=0; i<=myButtons.length-1; i++){
            myButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

    }
}
```

First time will sucess change all button color back to default,
but second times i call the function, are not working any more, anyone facing this BUG?
i m using API 9 Android 2.x.x

those button are dynamic buttons that i have saved in a button array, those button are created inside a scrollview

Comment: `are not working anymore`.  What happens?

Comment: @Simon the button won't change back the default color. when run the application only once can change back the button color, second times call the ClearbuttonColor will not change back any more.

Comment: my application when User pressed the button will change the button's background color, but they able to clear all the button background color when press clear button and will calling the clearButtonColor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clear the background resource,then new resource can be added:

```
public void ClearButtonColor(){
        for(int i=0; i<=myButtons.length-1; i++){
        myButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(0);
        myButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);    
    }
}
```

this will definitely work.

Comment: Haha ! it's work ! why must clear the resource first? i can't understand the logic

Comment: because it doesn't clear previous resources automatically, we always need to tell that by giving it zero as argument. @ChinYe